# Update fields using foreach in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to update multiple rows based on its unique field `taskCode`

and will update the field of `taskWeight` from `tbl_projtask`

I have this 2 variable

1. `$request->dataWeight`
   This variable is coming from ajax request that contains something like this `95,75,65` a value that is separated by commas.
2. `$request->dataWeightAttr` 
   This variable is coming from ajax request that contains something like this `TaskCode1, TaskCode2, TaskCode3`

In my `MainController.php`

I have this code

```
    $myString = $request->dataWeightAttr;
        foreach($myString as $value){
            DB::table('tbl_projtask')
            ->where('taskCode', $value)
            ->update([
            'taskWeight'=> $request->dataWeight,
            'by_id'=> auth()->user()->id,
            'updated_by'=> auth()->user()->name,
            'updated_at' => now()
            ]);
        }
```

As you can see in my `update` code

I used `request->dataWeightAttr` to find which rows should be updated and `$request->dataWeight` the value for specific `taskCode`

Am I doing this right?

Comment: You want to update  taskWeight related to taskCode?

Comment: yes I want to update taskWeight where taskCode is given from the `$request->dataWeightAttr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your string to an Array

```
$dataWeight = explode(',',$request->dataWeight); // convert to array
$dataWeightAttr = explode(',',$request->dataWeightAttr); // convert to array
```

Assuming you have related values in both array.

```
foreach($dataWeightAttr as $key => $value){
    DB::table('tbl_projtask')
    ->where('taskCode', $value)
    ->update([
    'taskWeight'=> $dataWeight[$key],
    'by_id'=> auth()->user()->id,
    'updated_by'=> auth()->user()->name,
    'updated_at' => now()
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use whereIn instead of foreach if you want to update same fields but different id.

```
 DB::table('tbl_projtask')
  ->whereIn('taskCode', $request->dataWeightAttr)
  ->update([
     'taskWeight'=> $request->dataWeight,
     'by_id'=> auth()->user()->id,
     'updated_by'=> auth()->user()->name,
     'updated_at' => now()
 ]);
```